# Regex assistance in R

Tags: r, string, replace

I am trying to manipulate the following sting

```
x = log(y(-1))
```

So that I can replace the (-1) with dplyr::lag(y)

I'm hoping my output to look like this

```
x = log(dplyr::lag(y))
```

The strings I will be dealing with will be much more complicated - the "y" could be a string any number of characters long. It will be preceded by either a mathematical expression or a parenthesis. For example, a string could look like this:

```
variable_1 = dlog(var_i_ble_2(-1))+vari_abl_e3(-1)
```

And I'd like that to look like

```
variable_1 = dlog(dplyr::lag(var_i_ble_2))+dplyr::lag(vari_abl_e3)
```

I'm not sure this is possible with a simple regex libraries in R - perhaps I need to use a number of regex/subs in a function?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Regex is not supposed to be used for parsing non-regular languages. If `y` can be any valid expression, you will need a parser.

Comment: To achieve what you want (if I understand correctly) you could do: `library(stringr)

string <- "variable_1 = dlog(var_i_ble_2(-1))+vari_abl_e3(-1)"
gsub("\\((-1)\\)", "dplyr::lag(y)", string)`